# Колорбокс-окно загружающий iframe

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Кастомный попап (Colorbox plugin), который подтягивает содержимое с стороннего адреса специально сверстанной html страницы, имеющею две кнопки - "ДА" (переход на указанную в коде страницу) и "НЕТ" которая должна закрывать попап (iframe).

Как закрыть колорбокс-окно, который загружает iframe по клику на кнопку "НЕТ" в этом же iframe?

была попытка таким образом:

```
<div class="button button-gray modal-button-close">
    <p class="btn_title">НЕТ</p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 (function($) {
   $('.modal-button-close').on( "click", function() {
    $('#modalContent .close').click();
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Пример кода в студию

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте свои разработки. И куча англоицизмов - это не круто, исправьте.

Comment: [Тут почитайте](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) - конкретно Вам нужно либо $.colorbox.close(), либо $.colorbox.remove(). Либо у Вас какой-то другой плагин - тогда неплохо было бы написать в вопросе какой именно плагин и как Вы его используете.

Comment: плагин colorbox, добавил код

Answer (score 0):

По [доке](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) там должен вызываться метод

`$('.modal-button-close').colorbox.close();`

Где `'.modal-button-close'` ваша кнопка "нет"

То есть вам нужно вызвать метод `close`, а не делать click по кнопке.